# How to tell which values of $p$ let this sum converge

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This is the sum:
$$\sum\limits_{n=3}^\infty\frac{1}{n\cdot\ln(n)\cdot\ln(\ln(n))^p}$$
How do I tell which values of $p$ allow this to converge? The ratio test isn’t working out for me at all.

Comment: This looks like a case for the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test . But are you sure that it is $\ln(\ln(n))^p$ instead of $(\ln\ln(n))^p$?

Comment: https://vincenttam.gitlab.io/post/2018-11-20-solution-to-a-p-test-exercise/

Answer (score 3):

The ratio test will not work because this series converges/diverges far too slowly for the test to give any information. Rather, the integral test is most useful when studying things related to $p$-series. In particular, if we set $u = \ln \ln x$ then we can find that

\begin{align*}
\int_3^{\infty} \frac{1}{x \ln x (\ln \ln x)^p} \, dx &= \int_{\ln \ln 3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{u^p} \, du
\end{align*}

which is now a vastly easier integral to study.